# Alexa grabbing spotify token from linked spotify account on alexa device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there any wayt o grab the token from your linked spotify account on alexa when building a custom alexa skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When someone links their Spotify account with their Alexa device, they're only granting Amazon permission to use the token, not 3rd party skill builders. You'll need to link your skill and Spotify with the account holder providing explicit permission for your skill to get a token.